# JavaScript: how to filter a nested Object based on a string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, filtering

I am a newbie to JavaScript. I have now a nested Object:

```
const fruitList = [
{   fruit: {id: '1-1', fruit_name: 'Apple'},
    location: {id: '2-1', location_name: 'USA'}
},
{
    fruit: {id: '1-2', fruit_name: 'Banana'},
    location: {id: '2-2', location_name: 'UK'}
},
{
    fruit: {id: '1-3', fruit_name: 'Orange'},
    location: {id: '2-1', location_name: 'USA'}
}
];
```

and a string array:

```
let keywords = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
```

I am trying to filter the nested Object based on the above string array and the expected outpust is :

```
output =[    
{   fruit: {id: '1-1', fruit_name: 'Apple'},
    location: {id: '2-1', location_name: 'USA'}
},
{
    fruit: {id: '1-2', fruit_name: 'Banana'},
    location: {id: '2-2', location_name: 'UK'}
}
];
```

I already tried:

```
const filteredFruit = fruitList.filter(({item})=>
    item.fruit?.fruit_name.every(ele => keywords.includes(ele))
)
```

but it didn't work. **I also checked all the similar questions on the Stackoverflow, but still could not find a way to solve it.** Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The fact that it is a nested property doesn't change the logic of the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

1. `item` isn't a property of the object being iterated on so you can't destructure it.
2. You need to swap around your condition to check to see if the keywords array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the fruit name.

```js
const fruitList=[{fruit:{id:"1-1",fruit_name:"Apple"},location:{id:"2-1",location_name:"USA"}},{fruit:{id:"1-2",fruit_name:"Banana"},location:{id:"2-2",location_name:"UK"}},{fruit:{id:"1-3",fruit_name:"Orange"},location:{id:"2-1",location_name:"USA"}}];

const keywords = ['Apple', 'Banana'];

const filteredFruit = fruitList.filter(item =>
  keywords.includes(item.fruit.fruit_name)
);

console.log(filteredFruit);
```